# javascript - pass a value from text input box to a variable, for use in Fetch API

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an input box with button. When I enter an input, i want that input to be passed to a variable called 'town' that i can use in my fetch API call.
When i try this, it says the variable is undefined.
To test, i can get the Fetch API to work if i define the variable 'town' as 'garstang' e.g.
var town ='garstang';

But i want to make 'town' get its input from the result of my input box, which is 'inputVal'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="js.js"></script>
  <title>Javascript Calling APIs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>

  <script>
    function getInputValue() {
      // Selecting the input element and get its value
      var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

      // Displaying the value
      alert(inputVal);
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "insert_key_here");

     var town ='garstang';
    // var town = inputVal;

    var url = "https://wyre-data.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/town";

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: 'follow'

    };

    fetch(url + '/' + town, requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      // .then(result => console.log(result))
      .then(result => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "<strong>The answer is: </strong>" + (result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  </script>
  <h2>The End...</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your fetching script executes before any manipulation with input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetching script executes before any manipulation with input field.
I moved code related to api call after pressing button.

[image: Image that shows actually filled value of town]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Javascript Calling APIs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>

    <script>
      function getInputValue() {
        // Selecting the input element and get its value
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

        // Displaying the value
        alert(inputVal);
        
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("x-rapidapi-key", "insert_key_here");

        //var town ='garstang';
        var town = inputVal;

        var url = "https://wyre-data.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/town";

        var requestOptions = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: myHeaders,
          redirect: 'follow'

        };

        fetch(url + '/' + town, requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.text())
          // .then(result => console.log(result))
          .then(result => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            "<strong>The answer is: </strong>" + (result))
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));  
      }
    </script>
    <h2>The End...</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inputVal` you declared in the `getInputValue` function become **local** to the function. That means it's not possible to access it from other scripts

See following link for more detailed explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Possible solutions:

- You put everything in one script.
- Or instead of `var town = inputVal` you do `var town = document.getElementById("myInput").value`